# Renombrar archivo de imagen subido por php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php 
 
/* 
 * Función personalizada para comprimir y 
 * subir una imagen mediante PHP
 */ 
 


 
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) { 
    // Obtenemos la información de la imagen
    $imgInfo = getimagesize($source); 
    $mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 
     
    // Creamos una imagen
    switch($mime){ 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
            break; 
        case 'image/png': 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); 
            break; 
        case 'image/gif': 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
            break; 
        default: 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
    } 
     
    // Guardamos la imagen
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality); 
     
    // Devolvemos la imagen comprimida
    return $destination; 
} 
 
 
// Ruta subida
$uploadPath = "uploads/";


// Si el fichero se ha enviado
$status = $statusMsg = ''; 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
    $status = 'error'; 
    if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) { 
        // File info 
         $empresa= $_POST["empresa"];
        $fileName = $empresa.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]); 
        $imageUploadPath = $uploadPath . $fileName; 
        $fileType = pathinfo($imageUploadPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

         
        // Permitimos solo unas extensiones
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif'); 
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
            // Image temp source 
            $imageTemp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
```

Buenas tardes, necesito renombrar el archivo subido, con el nombre $empresa. Lamentablemente al subir el archivo se sube con el nombre $empresa+nombredeorigen.extension.

Ej: Si yo al campo $empresa le doy el nombre "ABM"  y el nombre del archivo es "foto1.jpg" sube el archivo con el nombre ABMfoto1.jpg. POr lo mismo quiero que solo se renombre como "ABM.jpg"

Muchas gracias

Comment: Tu código está incompleto. ¿Cuál es la variable que usas para nombrar el archivo definitivo, que te está resultando en `ABMfoto1.jpg`?

Comment: $empresa= $_POST["empresa"];
 $fileName = $empresa.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);----como puedo crear esa variable?. Lo otro el codigo completo no me dejo ingresarlo...

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, deberías hacer algo así:

En lugar de esto, que resulta en ABMfoto1.jpg:

```
$fileName = $empresa.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

Cambiarlo por esto, que debería resultar en ABM.jpg:

```
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$fileName = $empresa . '.' . $file_info['extension'];
```

Es decir, del nombre de archivo original se toma sólo la extensión y se concatena con el valor de $empresa.